# versatile unzip utility

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zip

Is there a compression utility that will allow extracting a file while skipping the first (container) directory.

My purpose is to create an automated install script that will download a specific .zip, extract and install.  I want option to skip the container directory which is nearly always an undesirable name.

An example would be like using the rar option ep1

```
rar x -ep1 archive.rar
```

Comment: You want to _skip_ a directory? Or you just don't want the top-level directory within the archive created on extraction?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [p7zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/), the Unix command line port of the popular archiving tool [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). It may have the feature you are asking for, but I don't know what the command would exactly be.

If I understand correctly you could always try extracting the archive then doing:

```
cd archivename
mv * ..
rm -f archivename
```

This should move all the files from within the folder in to the directory above then delete the original containing folder.